# CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'double' to 'UnityEngine.Quaternion' HELP! unity 2D c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

```
        //pew pew
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

        Vector2 direction = new Vector2(mousePosition.x - transform.position.x, mousePosition.y - transform.position.y);
        var rad = Math.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x);
        var deg = rad * (180 / Math.PI);
        Debug.Log(deg);
        Instantiate(bulletprefab, firePoint.position, deg);
```

Hi! Basically, I am trying to shoot a bullet in the direction of the mouse, but cant find any answers I understand. I'm a beginner.

Comment: Idk why it says unity 3d, i specified 2d..

Comment: possibly show your imports and previous code if any and append whole error trace, which line of code produces the error?

Comment: Well deg is a number not a vector2... as it says.

Comment: "unity3d" is the tag for all things Unity. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the single **`float`** value `deg` to [`Instantiate(Transform, Vector3, Quaternion)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) in

```
Instantiate(bulletprefab, firePoint.position, deg);
```

It expects a rotation `Quaternion` as third parameter here!

Since this is supposed to be in 2D it means you are searching for a rotation about `deg` degrees on the global `Z` axis. Now there are multiple ways of how to get that. You could e.g. use [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html)

```
Instantiate(bulletprefab, firePoint.position, Quaternion.Euler(Vector3.forward * deg));
```